# Prometheus PromQL summary difference outer without field vs multi field

Tags: prometheus, summary, promql

What is the difference between 2 PromQLs below?

```
count without(instance)(
    sum without(handler)(rate(http_response_size_bytes_sum[5m]))
)
```

VS

```
count without(handler,instance)(rate(http_response_size_bytes_sum[5m]))
```

Comment: Without the data in your prometheus this question is hard to answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference: the `without` [aggregation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators)

> removes the listed labels from the result vector, while all other labels are preserved in the output

Chaining two `without` with the same operator or using a single one with both labels should yield the same result.

Depending on how nifty Prometheus request parser/compiler is, it could do it behind the scene. If not, there could be some slight overhead in Prometheus because it chains two operations instead of apply one with all criteria.